# When creating JavaScript objects with properties, why is this code necessary?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, prototype

I am reading about JavaScript prototypes [here](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/). Under the Object.create header, some code is written out to illustrate creating objects with prototypes and certain properties:

```
var person = {
    kind: 'person'
}

// creates a new object which prototype is person
var zack = Object.create(person);

console.log(zack.kind); // => ‘person’
```

I then encountered this:

```
var zack = Object.create(person, {age: {value:  13} });
console.log(zack.age); // => ‘13’
```

Instead of passing `{age: {value: 13} }`, I passed `{age: 13}` because it seemed simpler. Unfortunately, a `TypeError` was thrown. In order to create properties of this object like this, why do we have to pass `{age: {value: 13} }` rather than just `{age: 13}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the parameter is a properties object. You're not just defining fields, you're defining properties which is a bit of a different animal. For example you could specify the 'age' isn't writable. Refer to this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create